# JSF2 display old values on back button

Tags: caching, jsf-2

I made several test on PRG Pattern. I have also read many answers made in this site about back button issues. 
I insist on the fact that the code is a test.
So, at the beginning of the workflow a token is put on the session and at the end I remove this token from the session. 
When I press back button, I check if the token is not present and create a new instance of the property used in the facelet. From The transaction_done.xhtml page to the transaction_confirm.xhtml, it works: the facelet displays an empty form with an error messsage; but when I press the back button again to go to the transaction_register.xhtml page, the page display the old values with the error message.

I debug the code and the property at phase 6 is a new instance so I do not understand why the register page retrieves the old values. I also note that if I delete manually the jsessionid in chrome the old values disappear.
I also not that the viewstate on the register page is different when I press the back button that the value at the beginning of the workflow.

This test is thus made in chrome which calls by default the server on back button. FireFox do not call the server, it display the page frome the cache by default.
I know that I have to put a Filter with some value like no-cache... But I want to understand why it works from done to confirm page and not from confirm to register page.

I put the code of the managed bean and the 3 .xhtml.

Thanks in advance for your help.

A. ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TransactionBean implements Serializable {
    private ITransactionService transactionService;
    private VirtualDbAccountRepository accountRepository;
    private TransferTransaction currentItem;
    private List<TransferTransaction> transactionList;
    private List<SelectItem> accounts;
    private String id;
    private String nextOutcome;
    private static final String INIT_VIEW = "/home.xhtml";
    private static final String REGISTER_VIEW = "/transaction_register.xhtml";
    private static final String CONFIRM_VIEW = "/transaction_confirm.xhtml";
    private static final String DONE_VIEW = "/transaction_done.xhtml";
    private static final String LISTING_VIEW = "/transaction_listing.xhtml";
    private static final String CURRENT_ITEM = "currentItem";
    private static final String TOKEN = "token";
    private static final String CURRENT_ID = "currentId";

    public TransactionBean() {
        log();

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        log();
        transactionService = TransactionService.getInstance();
        accountRepository = new VirtualDbAccountRepository();
        handleByViewId(FacesUtil.getViewId());
    }

    private void handleByViewId(String viewId) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("The ViewState value is: "
                + FacesUtil.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter(
                        "javax.faces.ViewState"));
        log();
        if (viewId.equals(INIT_VIEW))
            handleInitView();
        if (viewId.equals(REGISTER_VIEW))
            handleRegisterView();
        if (viewId.equals(CONFIRM_VIEW))
            handleConfirmView();
        if (viewId.equals(DONE_VIEW))
            handleDoneView();
        if (viewId.equals(LISTING_VIEW))
            handleListingView();
    }

    private void handleInitView() {
        FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ITEM, new TransferTransaction());
        FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(TOKEN, TokenUtil.getRandomHexString());
    }   

    private void handleRegisterView() throws IOException {
        log();
        if (!FacesUtil.getFacesContext().isPostback()) {
            // to handle edit on confirmation page
            currentItem = (TransferTransaction) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(
                    CURRENT_ITEM);
            String token = (String) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(TOKEN);
            // only create new instance if token equals null.
            if (null == token) {
                currentItem = new TransferTransaction();                
                handleErrorPage();              
            }
            FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ITEM, currentItem);
            FacesUtil.getSessionMap()
                    .put(TOKEN, TokenUtil.getRandomHexString());
        } else
            currentItem = (TransferTransaction) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(
                    CURRENT_ITEM);
        fillSelectItems();
    }

    private void handleConfirmView() throws IOException {
        log();
        currentItem = (TransferTransaction) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(
                CURRENT_ITEM);
        String token = (String) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(TOKEN);
        if (null == token) {
            currentItem = new TransferTransaction();
            handleErrorPage();
        }
    }

    private void handleErrorPage() throws IOException {
        FacesUtil.getFacesContext().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        "The transaction has already been executed.",
                        "The transaction has already been executed."));

    }

    private void handleDoneView() {
        log();
        id = (String) FacesUtil.getSessionMap().get(CURRENT_ID);
        currentItem = transactionService.find(id);
    }

    private void handleListingView() {
        log();
        transactionList = new ArrayList<TransferTransaction>();
        transactionList = VirtualDbTransferTransactionRepository.getInstance()
                .list();
    }

    private void fillSelectItems() {
        log();
        accounts = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        Collection<Account> values = accountRepository.list();
        for (Account a : values) {
            SelectItem sItem = new SelectItem(a, a.getAccountId()); // value,
                                                                    // label
            accounts.add(sItem);
        }
    }

    public String initNewTransaction() {
        return "transaction_register?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String register() {
        log();
        String outcome = null;
        // to handle back button
        if (null != nextOutcome)
            outcome = nextOutcome;
        else
            outcome = "transaction_confirm?faces-redirect=true";
        return outcome;
    }

    public String preEdit(String id) {
        log();
        String outcome = null;
        currentItem = transactionService.find(id);
        FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ITEM, currentItem);
        FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(TOKEN, TokenUtil.getRandomHexString());
        outcome = "transaction_register?faces-redirect=true";
        return outcome;
    }

    public String add() {
        log();
        String outcome = null;
        TransactionResult transactionResult = transactionService
                .addTransaction(currentItem);
        if (!transactionResult.getStatusCodes().isEmpty()) {
            List<StatusCode> statusCodes = transactionResult.getStatusCodes();
            for (StatusCode statusCode : statusCodes) {
                FacesUtil.getFacesContext().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, statusCode
                                .getStatus(), statusCode.getCode()));
            }
            outcome = "transaction_confirm?faces-redirect=true";
        } else {
            // FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ITEM, null);
            // CURRENT_ID is used to handle done page
            FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ID,
                    transactionResult.getModel().getId().toString());
            FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(TOKEN, null);
            outcome = "transaction_done?faces-redirect=true";
            // transactionList.add(transactionResult.getModel());
        }

        return outcome;
    }

    public String modifyDate() {
        log();
        String outcome = null;
        TransactionResult transactionResult = transactionService
                .modifyTransaction(currentItem.getId(), currentItem.getDate());
        if (!transactionResult.getStatusCodes().isEmpty()) {
            List<StatusCode> statusCodes = transactionResult.getStatusCodes();
            for (StatusCode statusCode : statusCodes) {
                FacesUtil.getFacesContext().addMessage(
                        null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, statusCode
                                .getStatus(), statusCode.getCode()));
            }
            outcome = "transaction_confirm?faces-redirect=true";

        } else {
            // FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ITEM, null);
            // CURRENT_ID is used to handle done page
            FacesUtil.getSessionMap().put(CURRENT_ID,
                    transactionResult.getModel().getId().toString());
            // outcome = "transaction_listing?faces-redirect=true";
            outcome = "transaction_done?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        return outcome;
    }



    public TransferTransaction getCurrentItem() {
        log();
        return currentItem;
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(TransferTransaction currentItem) {
        this.currentItem = currentItem;
    }

    public List<TransferTransaction> getTransactionList() {
        return transactionList;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getAccounts() {
        log();
        return accounts;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void log() {
        PhaseId currentPhaseId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getCurrentPhaseId();
        System.out.println("+++ "
                + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()
                + " in phase : " + currentPhaseId.getOrdinal() + " at : "
                + new UtilDate().getTime());
    }


}
```

B. Pages

1.B. transaction_register.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h2>Home Bank</h2>
        <h4>Enter a new transaction</h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Debit Account Number</td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="debitAccount" value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.fromAccount}" 
                        disabled="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id != '-1'}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="Debit Account must be selected.">
                        <f:selectItem  noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="--------------"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{transactionBean.accounts}" />       
                        <f:converter converterId="transferTransactionConverter" />             
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Credit Account Number</td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="creditAccount" value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.toAccount}" 
                        disabled="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id != '-1'}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="Credit Account must be selected.">
                       <f:selectItem  noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="--------------"/>
                       <f:selectItems value="#{transactionBean.accounts}" />    
                       <f:converter converterId="transferTransactionConverter" />                      
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.amount}" disabled="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id != '-1'}" ></h:inputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id != '-1'}">
                <tr>
                    <td>Execution date</td>
                    <td>
                        <h:inputText value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.date}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </table>
        <p>
            <h:commandLink value="Create Transaction" action="#{transactionBean.register}" />           
        </p>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

2.B. transaction_confirm.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h2>Home Bank</h2>
    <h4>Confirm new transaction</h4>
    <h:messages showSummary="true" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Debit Account Number :</td>
            <td><h:outputText label="Debit Account Number"
                    value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.fromAccount.accountId}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Credit Account Number :</td>
            <td><h:outputText label="Credit Account Number"
                    value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.toAccount.accountId}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount :</td>
            <td><h:outputText label="Amount"
                    value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.amount}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id != '-1'}">
            <tr>
                <td>Execution date</td>
                <td><h:outputText value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.date}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText></td>
            </tr>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </table>
    <h:form>
        <div>
            <h:link value="Edit" outcome="transaction_register?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" />
        </div>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id eq '-1'}">
            <div>
                <h:commandButton value="Confirm" action="#{transactionBean.add}" />
            </div>  
        </h:panelGroup>     

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{transactionBean.currentItem.id gt '-1'}">
            <div>
                <h:commandButton value="Confirm date modification" action="#{transactionBean.modifyDate}" />
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>     

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

3.B. transaction_done.xhtml

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h2>Home Bank</h2>
        <h4>new transaction is executed.</h4>
        <h:messages />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Debit Account Number :</td>
                <td><h:outputText label="Debit Account Number"
                        value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.fromAccount.accountId}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Credit Account Number :</td>
                <td><h:outputText label="Credit Account Number" value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.toAccount}"  converter="transferTransactionConverter" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount :</td>
                <td><h:outputText label="Amount" value="#{transactionBean.currentItem.amount}" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br/>
        <h:link outcome="home.xhtml" value="Menu" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition, I also tried to add a Filter (NoCacheFilter) explained by BalusC without any succcess.

Comment: That filter is the answer. In order to verify if you implemented it rightly, does the headers get set when the page is requested? Have you verified it in browser's HTTP traffic monitor? And, when you press the back button, is the filter called again?

Comment: I advanced in my investigations. 
I still have the same problem in the Chrome browser...

However, I have established the same test in the Firefox browser and the behavior is correct thanks to the filter. In summary, Chrome and Firefox does not support the cache the same way even if the filter is present. If my test is correct, I think this difference of behavior in these two browsers very unpleasant. The two headers are exactly the same with "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"...
Otherwise @BalusC what do you think of this implementation of the PRG pattern?

Comment: I meant that the two headers are identical and as I said previously the behavior is different in Chrome and Firefox.
Here is the header :

Cache-Control no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length 2035
Content-Type text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date Wed, 04 Feb 2015 12:30:11 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma no-cache
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6, JSF/2.0

Do you have any idea why this difference?

Comment: @BalusC no idea why Chrome does not react like Firefox?